# Как сделать перенос через дефис слов в блоке?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать перенос через дефис слов в блоке?

```css
.block {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis deserunt quia voluptatibus rerum vero voluptate recusandae, assumenda eos voluptates odio, asperiores magnam aut commodi alias, quibusdam consectetur. Vitae earum, nisi.</div>
```

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/blog/perenosy-slov

Comment: @Hikikomori тут был совсем другой вопрос. Возможно баг какой-то

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поддержка пока только в **IE10, Firefox, Android и iOS.**

**Chrome и Opera** не поддерживают.

Обратите внимание на атрибут `lang="en"`, en - для английского текста, ru - для русского. Можно указать для всей страницы в теге `<html lang="en">`

```css
.block {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="block" lang="en">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis deserunt quia voluptatibus rerum vero voluptate recusandae, assumenda eos voluptates odio, asperiores magnam aut commodi alias, quibusdam consectetur. Vitae earum, nisi.</div>
```

Comment: эх, не работает auto в моём хроме на linux. Кстати, а разве остальным `text-align: justify;` не нужен?

Comment: @vp_arth, зависит от потребности